# Using a local resource defined on a ContentControl

Tags: wpf

I have a local resource that I want to use on a control. I'd like to define the resource directly on the control since that's the only place it's going to be used.

```
<Button Background="{StaticResource MyBrush}">
  <Button.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyBrush" Color="#FFD71526"/>
  </Button.Resources>
</Button>
```

This doesn't work MyBrush hasn't been defined at the time Background is set. It would work as a DynamicResource, but I want to keep it static.

**Question:** How can I set a property on a control using a resource that is defined  directly on the control?

I tried setting the property after creating the resource, but if it's possible I can't seem to find the correct syntax.

```
<Button>
  <Button.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyBrush" Color="#FFD71526"/>
  </Button.Resources>
  <Button.Background>
    {StaticResource MyBrush}
  </Button.Background>
</Button>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate why you want to do it 'this way' ? It kinda makes no sense and may be a  XY-Problem. And for the correct `Syntax` for the `Button` try `<SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyBrush}, Path=Color}"/>`.

Comment: That appears to be binding the color property of one brush to the color property of another. That means there are actually two brushes being created when only one is needed.

Comment: Correct, so your main concern is the Resource-Usage?

Comment: My main concern is understanding.

Comment: Why is it necessary for the `Resource` to be a `StaticResource`?  The main difference between `StaticResource` and `DynamicResource`is when & how they look-up the `Resource` (eg. a `StaticResource` is not exactly like a `static` in the Code, more details see here -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/xaml-resources#static-and-dynamic-resources)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax is the following one:

```
<Button>
  <Button.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyBrush" Color="#FFD71526"/>
  </Button.Resources>
  <Button.Background>
    <StaticResource ResourceKey="MyBrush" />
  </Button.Background>
</Button>
```

Answer (score -1):

if you do not want to use the color anywhere else there is no point in making a static ressource in the first place!
If it is one time use just put it in the property directly like this:

```
<Button Background="#FFD71526">
</Button>
```

Defining a color as a static ressource only makes sense on a parent with multible childs that plan to reuse that property

Edit: 
You can use this for your purpose, set the backround once and bind all other properties (for example BorderBrush) to the background like so:

```
<Button 
     Background="#FFD71526" 
     BorderBrush="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Background}"  
     BorderThickness="5">
</Button>
```

Comment: I want to use the same resource on multiple properties of the Button without copy-pasting the literal value all over the place.

Comment: there are better ways to do that but i updated my answer for you!